# Visible and hide UI Controller in iOS

Tags: android, ios, visible, invisible, ios-autolayout

I'm form Android background and learning iOS. There we have three property to hide and visible UI widget, VISIBLE, INVISIBLE & GONE but here in iOS I got VISIBLE and HiDDEN(INVISIBLE) only. So in case of auto-layout implementation how this thing will work.

Am I missing anything here!. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

They are different because Android layouts are more dynamically adaptable, similar to something like HTML - if you set something to be gone, then it is automatically no longer considered in the layout.

In iOS, constraints are less dynamic - you can't set something to be gone and have the layout automatically work. If you want to hide a view and also remove it from autolayout's consideration, you will need to set it to hidden and then also disable the constraints from that view to any other views. Also, in this case there is no guarantee you will not leave your autolayout constraints in an inconsistent state, so it is up to you to make sure that with those constraints removed, there are others that allow the layout to still resolve without ambiguity.

Comment: right, do u can guide any sample code how to shift constraints to other view at runtime.

Comment: @Shubh It's a broad topic and a different question from this one. There are various different ways you can do it depending on your needs - you can manually add and remove constraints, you can enable and disable sets of constraints created in Interface Builder, or you can have some constraints pre created with a lower priority which take over when higher priority constraints are disabled, etc - so I would recommend a different specific question.